# Values NOT being sent to mysql Database from Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, .post

I am trying to get jquery's .ajax() to send values sent to a form :

```
                    <form method="post" id="FanDetail">
                        <label for="bio">Brief Bio<br /></label>
                            <textarea id="bio" name="fan_bio" cols="27" rows="3"></textarea><br />
                        <label for="dob">Date of Birth<br/></label>
                            <input id="dob" name="fan_dob" value="(e.g. 01/05/1965)" onFocus="clearText(this)" /><br />     
                        <label for="zip">Location<br /></label>
                            <div class="ui-widget">
                                <input id="zip" name="term" value="What is your Zipcode?" onFocus="clearText(this)" /><br />
                                <input id="actualZip" type="hidden" name="actualzipval" value="" />
                            </div><!--ui-widget :: zip -->
                        <label for="occup">Occupation<br /></label>
                            <div class="ui-widget">
                                <input id="occup" type="text"  name="term2" value="e.g. Computer Programmer, etc" onFocus="clearText(this)" /><br />
                                <input id="actualOccup" type="hidden" name="actualOccupval" value="" />
                            </div><!--ui-widget :: occup -->
                        <label for="fbkurl">Facebook Handle&nbsp;[?]<br /></label>
                            <input id="fbkurl" type="text"  name="fan_fbk" value="e.g. SportsFan12" onFocus="clearText(this)" /><br />
                        <label for="twiturl">Twitter Handle&nbsp;[?]<br /></label>
                            <input id="twiturl" type="text"  name="fan_twit" value="e.g. AboutSports2012" onFocus="clearText(this)" /><br />
                        <label for="phoNum">Phone Number<br /></label>
                            <input id="phoNum" type="text"  name="fan_pho" value="cell or home phone" onFocus="clearText(this)" /><br />
                    <input style="background-image:url('img/save.png');" type="submit" name="saveAbout" value="" id="submit" />
                    </form>
<div class="success" style="display:none;">Got it!</div>
```

**This `HTML` connects to the `JS` file `submitvalues.js`**

```
//////////////// About Tab
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form#FanDetail").submit(function() {
    // store the values from the form input box, then send via ajax below
    var bio = $('#bio').val();
    var dob = $('#dob').val();
    var zip = $('#actualZip').val();
    var occup = $('#actualOccup').val();
    var fbkurl = $('#fbkurl').val();
    var twiturl = $('#twiturl').val();
    var phoNum = $('#phoNum').val();
    $.post(
            "../src/php/registration/about/submitvalues_about_tab.php",
            $("form#FanDetail").serialize(),
            function(){
                $('form#FanDetail').hide(function(){
                    $('div.success').fadeIn();
            });
          });
       return false;
    });
});
```

**This JS file, then connects to a php script that sends them to `mysql` via `PDO`**
UPDATED PHP:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////
######## Get  Input to Submit ############## //
///////////////////////////////////////////////
$fanBio = $_POST['bio'];             //////
$fanDob = $_POST['dob'];             //////
$zipval = $_POST['zip'];             //////
$occupval = $_POST['occup'];         //////
$facebookurl = $_POST['fbkurl'];         //////
$twitterurl = $_POST['twiturl'];         //////
$phoneNum = $_POST['phoNum'];        //////
$fanID = 1;
///////////////////////////////////////////////

try{
    ## Get current user and their session ID:
    $sessionvar = session_id();
    ### DB Connection already established above.
    $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );  
    // INSERT CLEAN DATA INTO TABLE…
    $sth = $dbh->prepare("
    UPDATE Fan 
    SET fanBio=?,fanDob=?,fanDetLocID=?,occupID=?,fanFbk=?,fanTwit=?,fanPho=?
    WHERE fanID = ?
    ");
    $sth->bindValue(1,$fanBio);
    $sth->bindValue(2,$fanDob);
    $sth->bindValue(3,$zipval);
    $sth->bindValue(4,$occupval);
    $sth->bindValue(5,$facebookurl);
    $sth->bindValue(6,$twitterurl);
    $sth->bindValue(7,$phoneNum);
    $sth->bindValue(8,$fanID);
    $sth->execute();
    $count = $stmt->rowCount(); // check row count
    $sth->debugDumpParams(); ## debugging query
}
```

Error I'm getting: **None**. It says after I fill in all the `input`s `Got it!` and thus it had fired off the `.success` class.

I tried:

- Manually entering in this information via mysql - works fine.
- Running Javascript Console to debug, it is sending it fine on the JS end, since I get this, once I click the send button:
  [image: img]

**When I fill in the input and look at the JS Console under Network->Response I get on the PHP FILE:**

```
   SQL: [107] 
    UPDATE Fan 
    SET fanBio=?,fanDob=?,fanDetLocID=?,occupID=?,fanFbk=?,fanTwit=?,fanPho=?
    WHERE fanID = 1

Params:  7
Key: Position #0:
paramno=0
name=[0] ""
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Position #1:
paramno=1
name=[0] ""
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Position #2:
paramno=2
name=[0] ""
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Position #3:
paramno=3
name=[0] ""
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Position #4:
paramno=4
name=[0] ""
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Position #5:
paramno=5
name=[0] ""
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Position #6:
paramno=6
name=[0] ""
is_param=1
param_type=2
```

**Should `$sth->execute();` have all the bound params in it as an array??**

Comment: why not use just a jquery ajax function instead of post

Comment: Would you mind showing a sample using my code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following i hope it will post  here is a more detailed tutorial oh how it works

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("form#FanDetail").submit(function() {
        // store the values from the form input box, then send via ajax below
        var bio = ;
        var dob = $('#dob').val();
        var zip = $('#actualZip').val();
        var occup = $('#actualOccup').val();
        var fbkurl = $('#fbkurl').val();
        var twiturl = $('#twiturl').val();
        var phoNum = $('#phoNum').val();
                  $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "../src/php/registration/about/submitvalues_about_tab.php"
                  data: "bio=" + bio + "&dob=" + dob +"&zip=" + zip + "&occup=" + occup      +"&fbkurl=" + fbkurl + "&twiturl=" + twiturl +"& phoNum=" +  phoNum,
                  }).done(function( msg ) {
                     $('div.success').fadeIn();
                 });
           return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: sorry, changing the JS does not work. Please see updated error above

Comment: Off topic: Why not serialize the form instead? it's much cleaner. http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: @Flukey it looks like what he was doing before I agree it faster but I was trying to redo it because the direct query string way may be more straight forward and cause less errors.

Comment: @CodeTalk i am not sure but it seems like the problem may be in your direct update part UPDATE Fan SET fanB......  try using the way they do it here http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp

Comment: I have never used PDO but it looks like the file breaks in the update part here is a tutorial on how to update using PDO http://www.codeofaninja.com/2012/01/pdo-update-records.html

Comment: @COLDTOLD - what do you think I should do, I keep getting nothing updated.